# Integral of derivative of delta function gives strange answer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differentiation, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

So I've been doing some QM and I keep coming across the following type of integrals:

$$
\int f(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta(x-x') dx.
$$

I know that I should integrate by parts but then I always get $0$, since:

$$
\int \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta(x-x') dx = 0.
$$

One such example that I encountered is the following:

[image]

So my question is: How do I evaluate such integrals?

Comment: Why would partial integration give $0$?! Whats wrong with the derivation you cite? Also, please do not use images, use MathJax for math symbols and equations. And give the exact reference.

Comment: Well, when you integrate by parts, you have two terms. Your vanishing term is only one of those.

Comment: So using integration by parts we have 

$$
\int udv = uv - \int vdu
$$

but taking dv to be
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta(x-x') dx
$$

gives v=0, so uv = 0 and vdu =0
But here it seems that vdu is not 0... So why's that?

Comment: v is not zero, uv is not zero, only [uv] happens to be zero by other parts of our assumptions, and vdu is also not zero.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very confused, why is v non-zero? but uv is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you have to use integration by parts. The first term, $f(x)\delta(x-x')$ has to be evaluated at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. Those 2 vanish because the Dirac delta is zero everywhere except for $x=x'$. The remaining part is simply
$$ -\int \mathrm{d}x \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\delta(x-x') = -\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\big|_{x'}$$

You can get an intuitive picture by approximating the Delta function by a nascent version, and thinking about its derivative. It would look like a function with two sharp peaks, the first positive and the second negative, very close to each other. This effectively extracts from the integral the values of $f(x-\Delta x/2)$ and $f(x+\Delta x/2)$, where $\Delta x$ is the width of the nascent delta. It is now clear where the minus derivative of $f$ comes from, except for the missing $1/\Delta x$. This factor actually comes from the fact that the derivative of the nascent delta function is roughly scaled by a factor of $1/\Delta x$ with respect to the nascent delta itself.

In the figure, the orange line represents $dv$, which is the derivative of $v$. As you can see, $v$ is not zero, but instead becomes a delta function in the appropriate limit.

[image]

Comment: I still can't work this out. So using integration by parts:
$$
\int f(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta (x-x') dx \\

u=f(x), \\
dv=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta (x-x') dx \\
du = df, \\
v = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta (x-x') dx = 0
$$

hence uv = $0$ and vdu should also be $0$, no?

Comment: Your problem is in $v$. You need a $v$ to be a "function" whose derivative gives you the derivative of a delta function. I'm being a bit lax here with the formalism of distributions, but in plain english, a function whose derivative is the derivative of a delta function, is a delta function. So the correct function for $v$ is not 0, but a delta function, which is 0 everywhere except at $x=x'$. You can use a nascent delta to reproduce the steps of integration by parts with more intuition. I will add some figures to illustrate this in the answer.

Comment: @GytisVejelis The problem is that you set $du=df$, but then all of a sudden $dx$ appears in the integral.  You should really have $du = \frac{df}{dx}dx$, and in place of $dx$ in your final expression, it should be $\frac{df}{dx}dx$, which is what Diego has and is what is written in the excerpt in your OP. You're just using integration by parts wrong.